# XML error: SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing

Tags: wordpress, syndication

I get this error trying to fetch my rss feed using wordpress syndication (FeedWordPress).
In apache logs there are no records about trying to fetch it.
Looks like wordpress ignores it.
Url to my rss is right, I tried to fetch digg rss and it was fetched ok.
Why wordpress doesn't request my rss url?